# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column Laravel

Tags: join, laravel-5, roles

I receive this error when I want to couple a role to a user:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `roles_user` (`created_at`, `roles_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (2015-09-12 09:37:35, 2, 2015-09-12 09:37:35, 1))

This is my roles migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::table('roles')->insert(array(
        array('name' => 'user'),
        array('name' => 'admin'),
        ));
}
```

This is my users migration:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('roles_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And this is my pivot table:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles_user',function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In my roles model I'm saying:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\roles')->withTimestamps();
} here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't know why you have

```
$table->integer('roles_id')->unsigned();
```

in your `users` table? This would be in case you'd like to have one and only one role per user. But your many-to-many relationship here suggests you need a user to be able to have more than one role. So I would get rid of this line.

And then the belongsToMany relationship should take a Role model, not the table of the model.

```
class Role extends Model {
    protected $table = 'roles';
}

class User extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```